# Find and classify all the equilibrium solutions of the following system:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{gather}\frac{dx}{dt} = 7x − 4x^2 − 3xy\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = 5y − 2y^2 − 3xy\end{gather}
Hint: this models a system without coexistence.

I found the critical points (which I'm pretty sure are the equilibrium solutions please correct me if I'm wrong). They are
(0,0)  (7/4,0)  (1,1)  (0,0)
I do not know where to go from here though.

Comment: Please format your questions into [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You've been on this site for nearly 2 years, and asked 9 questions. It's time to learn!

Comment: @Allie: I get $$\{x\to 0,y\to 0\},\left\{x\to 0,y\to \frac{5}{2}\right\},\{x\to 1,y\to 1\},\left\{x\to \frac{7}{4},y\to 0\right\}$$ Next, find the Jacobian and the eigenvalues at each critical point.